# Why is the end result of my list in ascending order

Tags: python, list, if-statement, encryption

i was trying to make a very crude encryption system which will give a numerical value to every letter. The whole thing works fine except the end result is a list(which is supposed to happen) which is in ascending order(which is not supposed to happen.

the code is given below(it is very large)

```
a = 'a'
b = 'b'
c = 'c'
d = 'd'
e = 'e'
f = 'f'
g = 'g'
h = 'h'
i = 'i'
j = 'j'
k = 'k'
l = 'l'
m = 'm'
n = 'n'
o = 'o'
p = 'p'
q = 'q'
r = 'r'
s = 's'
t = 't'
u = 'u'
v = 'v'
w = 'w'
x = 'x'
y = 'y'
z = 'z'
numlist = []


s = input("input you sentence ")
l = list(s)



count = l.count(a)

for i in range(1,count+1):
    numlist.append(1)


count = l.count(b)

for i in range(1,count+1):
    numlist.append(2)


count = l.count(c)

for i in range(1,count+1):
    numlist.append(3)


count = l.count(d)
for i in range(1, count + 1):
    numlist.append(4)

count = l.count(e)
for i in range(1, count + 1):
    numlist.append(5)

count = l.count(f)
for i in range(1, count + 1):
    numlist.append(6)

count = l.count(g)
for i in range(1, count + 1):
    numlist.append(7)

count = l.count(h)
for i in range(1, count + 1):
    numlist.append(8)

count = l.count(i)
for i in range(1, count + 1):
    numlist.append(9)

count = l.count(j)
for i in range(1, count + 1):
    numlist.append(10)

count = l.count(k)
for i in range(1, count + 1):
    numlist.append(11)

count = l.count(l)
for i in range(1, count + 1):
    numlist.append(12)

count = l.count(m)
for i in range(1, count + 1):
    numlist.append(13)

count = l.count(n)
for i in range(1, count + 1):
    numlist.append(14)

count = l.count(o)
for i in range(1, count + 1):
    numlist.append(15)

count = l.count(p)
for i in range(1, count + 1):
    numlist.append(16)

count = l.count(q)
for i in range(1, count + 1):
    numlist.append(17)

count = l.count(r)
for i in range(1, count + 1):
    numlist.append(18)

count = l.count(s)
for i in range(1, count + 1):
    numlist.append(19)

count = l.count(t)
for i in range(1, count + 1):
    numlist.append(20)

count = l.count(u)
for i in range(1, count + 1):
    numlist.append(21)

count = l.count(v)
for i in range(1, count + 1):
    numlist.append(22)

count = l.count(w)
for i in range(1, count + 1):
    numlist.append(23)

count = l.count(x)
for i in range(1, count + 1):
    numlist.append(24)

count = l.count(y)
for i in range(1, count + 1):
    numlist.append(25)

count = l.count(z)
for i in range(1, count + 1):
    numlist.append(26)
    


    

print(numlist)
```

the output when i give the input zzzaaa is

```
input you sentence aaazzz
[1, 1, 1, 26, 26, 26]
```

this is not supposed to happen

i converted the whole alphabet into a single string and used the in function to find letters but instead it print the numbers 1 to 26 regardless of input

the output i was expecting was [26,26,26,1,1,1]

Comment: instead of making your code unnecessarily long why dont you just use a string like that `alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`

Comment: Please share an example of the output you expect. That will help to understand what changes are needed to get you there.

Comment: `[1, 1, 1, 26, 26, 26]` seems like the correct output for `'aaazzz'`. The resulting list is always in ascending order, because you're appending higher values each time, and aren't taking their position in the sentence into account.

Comment: Regardless of the input the answer is still in ascending order

Comment: The output is given in the text

Comment: I have already tried fitting the whole alphabet into a single string it just prints the number from 1 to 26 regardless of the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you have created multiple for loops and they start form the condition for 'a' and end for 'z'. You can't change this because the execution of this code start from the first line and ends at the last one by one. You've assigned the condition for count=count.l(a) first hence it will be executed first no matter the string you give (Even if you give your input string as 'za' it will give output as '[1,26] because the for loop 'a' is executed first). There is a drastic way to change this code and minimize the line usage to a great extent.

```
s = input("Input your sentence: ").lower() 
numlist = []

for i in s:
    if 'a' <= i <= 'z':
        numlist.append(ord(i) - ord('a') + 1)

print(numlist)
```

In this code,

1.first you will get the input string and it will be converted to lowercase using the lower() function.

2.After that you create an empty list 'numlist' and use for loop to get the letters of the string.

3.Then if 'a' <= char <= 'z': condition checks if the character is a letter of the English alphabet. This is done to exclude spaces, punctuation, and other non-alphabetic characters.

4.ord(char) - ord('a') + 1 calculates the numerical position of the letter in the alphabet. ord(char) returns the ASCII code of the character, and subtracting ord('a') adjusts the value to start from 0 for 'a'. Adding 1 adjusts the range to start from 1 as you intended.

5.Then the resulting position is appended to the numlist list.

6.Finally, the numlist is printed, containing the numerical positions of the letters in the input sentence as you wanted your code to get executed.

This is the most simplicit way to execute the above mentioned huge python code.

Comment: since i am a very beginner level programmer i am familiar with the ord() function but i dont understand why you subtract ord(a) and add 1 to it. could you please explain

Comment: Please care for details. There's a difference between `ord(a)` and `ord('a')`. But to answer your question: That happens so the numbers start at `1`.

Comment: okay so, let us consider the string you've provided as input is 'aazz' and it will give you the value '[1,1,26,26]. The value of 'z' is calculated as follows:  " ord(i) - ord('a') + 1"                        The ord(i) is the ASCII value of that letter. Consider i as 'z' that means ord(z) = 122(check for ASCII values in google). and the ASCII value of 'a' = 97 so the Statement  " ord(i) - ord('a') + 1"  gives us "122-97+1" which is 26 and the value of the alphabet 'z'.